# chrome remove print preview (--disable-print-preview) is working, after removing it from target also affecting

Tags: google-chrome

for removing print preview i use (--disable-print-preview) in target, and its working fine.

my problem is after i delete (--disable-print-preview) from target, its still affecting print preview( cant get print preview), is there any way without uninstalling?

Answer (score 0):

I think the --disable-print-preview is not supported anymore at version 39. I think is already not functioning even at the current version. Try to download the latest